# Polynomial division in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I see an exercise that says

> Find the quotient and remainder when $x^3+2$ is divided by $2x^2+3x+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, I cannot do $2x^2\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}x=x^3$. How am I supposed to divide then?

Comment: Have you checked your textbook to see if it defines division with remainder in such a ring? I can think of at least two reasonable definitions; one of which the quotient is a *rational* polynomial, and in the other the quotient is zero.

Comment: @Hurkyl Strangely, it doesn't. It only defines the division algorithm for polynomials over a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division is not possible  in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ since the leading coeff of $\,x^3\!+2\,$ is odd, but the leading coeff of  $\,(2x^2\!+3x+4) q(x)+r(x)\,$ is even. But it is possible if you first scale the dividend by $\,\color{#c00}{2}^2 = 4$

$$ 4(x^3\!+2)\ =\ (2x-3)\, (\color{#c00}2x^2+3x+4) + x+20$$

**Remark** $\ $ An analogous statement holds true generally, i.e. the division can be made fraction-free by scaling the dividend by a power of the lead coeff $\,c\,$ of the divisor, since the division algorithm over the fraction field (iteratively) divides only by $\,c,\,$  so only introduces denominators involving powers of $\,c.\,$ Essentially the division takes places in the extension ring $\,\Bbb Z[1/c]\subset \Bbb Q\,$ obtained by adjoining an inverse of $\,c.\,$ There the divisor has unit (invertible) leading coeff, so the division algorithm works fine. Such matters will become clearer when one learns about *localizations*.